# Converting data- data in one column into several columns

Tags: r

I am a new R user and I have the following problem:

I have data in two columns. First column contains markers and the second column contains the genotypes. Each genotype has say 4 markers. Thus, I have in the first column 4 times the name of genotype 1 and the according 4 markers, then genotype 2 follows with exact the same 4 markers and so on. But I want the markers in one column and the genoytpes each in one seperate column, so I can compare the markers across the genoytypes. I have no idea how I could do it.

G1 has 4 markers, G2 has the same 4 markers etc.:

```
-Marker Genotype
M1  G1
M2  G1
M3  G1
M4  G1
M1  G2
M2  G2
M3  G2
M4  G2
M1  G3
M2  G3
M3  G3
M4  G3
```

And I want R to to this:

```
Marker  G1  G2  G3
M1  AA  AA  GG
M2  TT  GG  CC
M3  GG  AA  AA
M4  CC  TT  GG
```

Put each genotype in one column so that the comparison of markers is very easy.

Has someone a bright idea of how that could work?

Thanks very much in advance.
Marie

Comment: maybe this is implied by some sort of domain specific knowledge, but where do the values "AA", "GG", "CC", and "TT" come from?

Comment: I concur with @Chase. You can generally solve this by using `reshape`, but your results include information that is not in the data.

Comment: It would be important to know whether each marker is associated with exactly three genotypes.

Comment: Each genotype has different Letters (AA, GG, TT etc) for each marker.Thus, the genotype is a person  and marker is a trait (eye colour, hair color) and each person has a different value for each trait (some have brown hair, some black etc).

Answer (score 1):

You want some sort of `cast`. For example

```
require(reshape2)

indata <- data.frame(  Marker = rep(c("M1","M2","M3","M4"), 3),
     Genotype = rep(c("G1","G2","G3"), each=4),
     value = c("AA","TT","GG","CC","AA","GG","AA","TT","GG","CC","AA","GG") )

outdata <- dcast(indata, Marker ~ Genotype)
```

will take you from

```
> indata
   Marker Genotype value
1      M1       G1    AA
2      M2       G1    TT
3      M3       G1    GG
4      M4       G1    CC
5      M1       G2    AA
6      M2       G2    GG
7      M3       G2    AA
8      M4       G2    TT
9      M1       G3    GG
10     M2       G3    CC
11     M3       G3    AA
12     M4       G3    GG
```

to

```
> outdata
  Marker G1 G2 G3
1     M1 AA AA GG
2     M2 TT GG CC
3     M3 GG AA AA
4     M4 CC TT GG
```